# How to intercept Firebase login event "failed: permission_denied"

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I use firebase for the google login in my app.
The rules allow login only for my company domain. 
When I use a @mydomain.com mail, the user log in correctly.
When I try to sign in with another mail, I have only a message in console like this:

```
[Firebase/Database][-----] Listener at /user_profiles/... failed: permission_denied.
```

but the app remains on the login view controller and nothing appens.

There is a way to intercept this message so I can show an alert on screen?

[my code in app delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4Xof.jpg)

This is not a login error because gmail login and firebase login works and errors never be invoked.
The error is a write/read errore due to my restriction for company domain.
Where I can handle the read/write error?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Use Firebase library to configure APIs
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    return true
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                             sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                             annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}

//let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil)




func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

    if let error = error {
        print("error:")
        print(error.localizedDescription) // never called

        return
    }
    print("Gmail login - OK")

    let authentication = user.authentication
    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: (authentication?.idToken)!,accessToken: (authentication?.accessToken)!)

    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print("error:")
            print(error.localizedDescription) // never called
            return
        }
        print("Firebase login - OK")

        self.databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
        self.databaseRef.child("user_profiles").child(user!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            let snapshot = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            if(snapshot == nil) {
                self.databaseRef.child("user_profiles").child(user!.uid).child("name").setValue(user?.displayName)
                self.databaseRef.child("user_profiles").child(user!.uid).child("email").setValue(user?.email)
            }


            self.window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "HomeViewSegue", sender: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This is caused by your rules - however, without seeing your login code, Firebase Rules and Structure we won't be able to answer. However, you can can handle Firebase errors in any Firebase closure following a Firebase call. Many have an error var that's set which contains the error.

Comment: I updated the post with my code. The Firebase closures are never called because login works. Where I can check the read/write error?

Comment: Closures *always* execute so you can perform other functions on sign in or handle any errors. In your case that error is not being thrown by the sign in, it's being called when you try to access a node that has rules set to deny permission. This line *self.databaseRef.child("user_profiles").child(user!.uid).observeSingleEvent* is throwing the error and there's no error handling code. That node has read evaluating for false, hence the error.

Answer (score -1):

Solved! I added this check:

```
            self.databaseRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { data in }, withCancel: { (returnedError: Error) in

            let testError: NSError = returnedError as NSError

            print("Firebase error:\(testError)")

        })
```

Comment: This is probably not a good solution as it's going to give you the same error as the one I addressed in my comment to your question. More importantly, if there is no error, this code adds an observer to the entire database so any children added anywhere we cause an event to occur. The *BIG* issue is that if you've got 10,000 nodes, this code is going to iterate over every single node in your entire database on startup for no reason. That's probably going to slow things WAY down.